# Java, what's going to be different when initializing an object from different reference?

Tags: java

when 2 classes are created as super and subclass.  what would be working differently if one of the objects was declared with a different reference?

```
class SubClass extends SuperClass

SubClass   s1 = new SubClass();
SuperClass s2 = new SubClass();
```

compare to the next one

```
class SubClass extends SuperClass

SubClass s1 = new SubClass();
SubClass s2 = new SubClass();
```

Comment: Polymorphism...

Comment: In the first case, you can only invoke methods defined on `SuperClass` on `s2`.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what does polymorphism do.  is it the override ability to the method?

Comment: Try to give Superclass a method, which you override in Subclass. Then go see, which one is invoked when you call it on each reference.

Comment: both called the SubClass method

Comment: 'Dough ... java ... switching between the worlds too often, sorry. Nevermind above comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class SubClass extends SuperClass

1) SubClass   s1 = new SubClass();

2) SuperClass s2 = new SubClass();

Explanation of first one:-

s1 is the refernce of subclass and holds a object of sub class, so it will call the method of subclass as well as super class because we extends the superclass method with subclass method so superclass method  will automatically available to subclass.we can call both super class as well as sub class method with the help of s1.

Explanation of second one:-

s2 is the refernce of Superclass and holds a object of sub class,so here two case we have to consider 
i) Method overloading:-method overloading is handle at compile time so it will  always call the method of superclass

ii)Method overriding:-method overriding is handle at runtime so it always call the method of subclass. the concept came from the polymorphism.

SubClass s1 = new SubClass();

SubClass s2 = new SubClass();

both s1 and s2 are reference of subclass and holding the object of subclass so in both case it will call the subclass object.

Answer (score 2):

Benefit of polymorphism is in ability to have multiple implementations. As you can see from the code below that function `letsHear` accepts **any** type of `Animal`. So this method is agnostic, it doesn't care what type of animal are you passing.

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract String talk();
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    String talk() {
        return "Meow!";
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    String talk() {
        return "Woof!";
    }
}

void letsHear(final Animal a) {
    println(a.talk());
}

int main() {
    letsHear(new Cat());
    letsHear(new Dog());
}
```

Concrete implementation could be assigned to it's parent.

```
Animal cat = new Cat();
Animal dog = new Dog();
```

If the method `letsHear` from the example above would accept only `Cat` then you would be required to have another method which accepts `Dog`.

Answer (score 1):

Try always to use the highest class you can. It gives you more flexibility by leaving you the possibility to switch the subclass later on. If your are just using it localy, it isn't that much of a great deal and you could probably change the whole definition without any side effects, but even it would be better to use the SuperClass. It would indicate that in this context **you just need the functionality defined in the SuperClass** and that's the important part.

It's much more important inside the parameters. Imagine the java standard library developer would've defined the Collections methods to take SubClasses like ArrayList. Not only much more code would be needed to take on every SubClass of the Collection interface, it would be incomplete once one creates a new subclass.

Summary: Always ask your self which functionality you really need to accomplish your operation and which superclass is needed for that. Is it List? Collection? Maybe Iteratable? Take the most abstract one.

Answer (score 1):

1. invoking a methods gonna work differently, if method's declared in subclasses do not exists in super class then they are not visible for reference variable of superclass. but you still can invoke them with downcasting,  READ  More About Static and Dynamic polymorphism,
2. invoking static method gonna work differently. check the example.

   ```
   public class BaseClass {

   public void compileSomeThing(){
   System.out.println("Base Method ");
   }
   public static void doSomething(){
   System.out.println("Base static method");
   }
   }
   ```

   base class

   ```
   public class SubClass  extends BaseClass{

   public void compileSomeThing(){
   System.out.println("Sub Method" );

   }
   public static void doSomething(){
   System.out.println("Sub static method");
   }
   }
   ```

   sub class. 
   and main class:

   ```
   public static void main(String[]args){
   BaseClass bs = new SubClass();
   SubClass bs1 = new SubClass();
   bs.compileSomeThing();
   bs.doSomething();
   System.out.println("..........");
   bs1.compileSomeThing();
   bs1.doSomething();
   ```

   }

result of compilation:

```
    Sub Method
    Base static method
      ..........
    Sub Method
   Sub static method
```

3. read more about: method, overloading, method overriding and method hiding. http://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-in-java  http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/runtime-compile-time-polymorphism/
   http://crunchify.com/java-method-hiding-and-overriding-override-static-method-in-java/

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> SubClass   s1 = new SubClass();
> SuperClass s2 = new SubClass();
> ```

On `s2` you can only invoke methods declared in `SuperClass`.
On `s1` you can invoke methods declared in `SuperClass` as well as methods declared in `SubClass`.